# check session of different browser

Tags: php, session, jquery

I'm developing a multiplayer Tic-Tac-Toe game. but the issue which I'm facing at the moment. is to know whether the other player is in the game or not. which I mean is to check whether the player2 session exists or not. if the session does not exist the game should end. how can I know whether the other player session exists or not?

Comment: what is the code that you have tried ?

Comment: i cannot think of any code. because they are in two different browser. and I have to check whether the other player session exists or not . and its in a different browser. How can I know whether the other player session exists or not

Comment: You have a LOT of different options.  The coolest would be to use websockets connecting each client to the server, and the server, telling each client if the other is still active.

Comment: I have not implemented websockets. its purely depending on database. every move is stored in database.

Comment: You could do it using database as you are currently doing... I don't get where you are failing, you should post what have you tried and how it fails in order to get more precise answers

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a server that will watch for each match going on and it's players. Client will repeatedly contact this server for new players or in your case valid players with sessions running. But I suggests you to use websockets instead. That will be much faster or online games.